# Nested forEach, both for pushing data in array, but the other one is showing 0 length in console

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```
async function GetUserRecords(dbUID){
const dbUserRef = collection(db, "profile");
const dbUserResRef = collection(db, "profile", dbUID, "records");
const q = query(dbUserResRef, orderBy('date', 'desc'), limit(1));

onSnapshot (q, (querySnapshot2)=>{
    // for (let doc2 of querySnapshot2){
    querySnapshot2.forEach(doc2 =>{
        const data1 = doc2.data();
        usersRecords.push(doc2.data());
    })
});}



async function GetAllDataRealtime(){
const dbUserRef = collection(db, "profile");

 onSnapshot (dbUserRef, (querySnapshot)=>{
     users = [];
     usersRecords = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{

         var dbUID = doc.data().id;
         GetUserRecords(dbUID);
         users.push(doc.data());
     });
     AddAllItemsToTable(users, usersRecords)
})



window.onload = GetAllDataRealtime();
```

im using this code to get data in firestore and output it in a table, but when I run it, one of the two arrays will have a data inside but the length of it is 0, so it makes it never shows data in my table

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve and what is not coming as expected. Can you provide more details of the issue? Also, can you mention how and where you are showing the output in the table?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your Firestore data/structure to understand the issue better.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9tfD67Z.png this is the output, i think because of the other array showing 0 size/length that the table is not showing, i found a another way but it's not a efficient/proper(i think) so i want a other or proper way.

Comment: Can you just `console.log()` both the arrays before `AddAllItemsToTable(users, usersRecords)` and see if there is data present in both of them?

Comment: @Prabir it's in my previous comment